# Noob questions.. iframe Resizer

Tags: iframe-resizer

I'm using wordpress and I'm attempting to add this http://davidjbradshaw.github.io/iframe-resizer/
to the my wordpress sites.

This is the page I'm adding as an iframe: http://www.abc-legal.reviews/abc-embed/

I've added this JS at the top of that page:

```
var iframes = iFrameResize( [{options}], [css selector] || [iframe] );
```

Should I be making changes to this at all? I.e should I add my own css selector etc.. what would I put under iframe?

Generally I'm just a bit confused, has anyone had success using this in two wordpress sites? Could someone give me a clear step of instructions?

Edit: this is the console error I'm getting: Uncaught ReferenceError: iFrameResize is not defined

Answer (score 0):

It might that you first need to load the `iframe` elements and only after apply the resize plugin.
Try to call the `iFrameResize` function only after the DOM has loaded:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  iFrameResize(/*...*/);
});
```

Comment: can you expand on this a bit?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but it seems like a classic race condition issue between the time the DOM is fully loaded and when you try to access it.
Because you put the code *at the top of that page*, it's very likely that the code will be executed before the `iframe` elements will be available in the page. Thus, your resizer has no element to apply it's logic to.

Comment: You just need to wait until the `<iframe>` tag is rendered on to the page, the script will detect when the content of the frame is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just do this and it needs to be placed at the bottom of the page.

```
var iframes = iFrameResize()
```